# Why does my solution undercount the answer — 2015 AMC 10A #22

Tags: probability, combinatorics

[Link to problem and solution](https://www.artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php?title=2015_AMC_12A_Problems/Problem_17)

> Eight people are sitting around a circular table, each holding a fair coin. All eight people flip their coins and those who flip heads stand while those who flip tails remain seated. What is the probability that no two adjacent people will stand?

I went about this by considering cases where you had $1$ head, $2$ heads, etc., and then using stars-and-bars (considering the stars to be the tails arranged in the circle and the bars to be possible slots in between the Tails) to find the number of ways to place the $n$ heads given $8-n$ tails.

For $0$ head, you would have $\binom{8}{0}$ ways, for $1$ heads, $\binom{7}{1}$, and so on, resulting in:

$$\binom{4}{4}+\binom{5}{3}+\binom{6}{2}+\binom{7}{1}+\binom{8}{0}$$ (since when you have 5 or more heads it is impossible to surround them with tails).

This, however, seems to undercount the correct answer by $13$. In the linked solution (which dome something similar but considers a linear arrangement instead of a circular one), they say that:

> Now we consider that the far right person can be standing as well, so we have ${3 \choose 3}+{4 \choose 2}+{5 \choose 1}+{6 \choose 0}=1+6+5+1=13$ ways Together we have $34+13=47$.

How does this extra case map to the circular arrangement, and why did my solution undercount the answer?

[image]

Comment: At least one undercounting that might provide a starting point: for the 4 heads case you suggest that there are ${4\choose 4}=1$ ways of 'inserting' the heads into the slots to get a legal configuration, but there are clearly two - one where all the 'odd' seats have flipped heads, and one where all the 'even' seats have.

Comment: @Arthur Whoops typoed there; now corrected.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki In the same way, if one person got heads, there are clearly $8$ places he could be, not $\binom 71 = 7$. Now, if they were placed in a line, and not a circle, and for every one standing, you made sure that the person on their right was seated, and _at the same time_, the rightmost person is seated, then you get $34$ possible solutions. That is the argument they use in the linked solution.